# How to combine two batch operations for views data export into one?

Tags: 7, views

I have been using a custom module that was posted here:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1875456

I slightly modified this module and created two copies of it, as I have two views and planning to add third one but it currently doesn't work properly so let me explain:

dvm_reports module#1 for Denmark

```
function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_alter(&$batch, &$batch_redirect) {
  $view = views_get_view($batch['produkty_denmark_xml']);

  // Add in another operation that will store the file on the server in a location
  // of our choosing.
  $batch['operations'][] = array(
    'dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish', array($batch['eid']),
  );
}

function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish($eid) {
  $export = views_data_export_get($eid);
  $view = views_data_export_view_retrieve($eid);
  $view->set_display($export->view_display_id);
  $view->display_handler->batched_execution_state = $export;
  $view->display_handler->remove_index();

  // Get path to temp file
  $temp_file = $view->display_handler->outputfile_path();
  file_unmanaged_copy($temp_file, 'public://denmark.xml', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```

It starts to generate the file correctly when I go to domain.com/denmark

dvm_reports module#2 for Sweden (I copied the denmark module and renamed it from "dvm_reports" to "dvm_reports2")

```
function dvm_reports2_views_data_export_batch_alter(&$batch, &$batch_redirect) {
  $view = views_get_view($batch['produkty_json']);

  // Add in another operation that will store the file on the server in a location
  // of our choosing.
  $batch['operations'][] = array(
    'dvm_reports2_views_data_export_batch_finish', array($batch['eid']),
  );
}

function dvm_reports2_views_data_export_batch_finish($eid) {
  $export = views_data_export_get($eid);
  $view = views_data_export_view_retrieve($eid);
  $view->set_display($export->view_display_id);
  $view->display_handler->batched_execution_state = $export;
  $view->display_handler->remove_index();

  // Get path to temp file
  $temp_file = $view->display_handler->outputfile_path();
  file_unmanaged_copy($temp_file, 'public://produkty.json', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```

it starts to generate the file correctly when I go to domain.com/sweden

**Problems:**

I would like to combine those two modules into one but I don't know how to do it.

Please advice if you can

Comment: What is the actual "requirement" you're trying to resolve with that custom module you stumbled upon? Just a wild guess, something like creating an XML of JSON file to actually export the results of some data you extraced from your Drupal DB usiing a view? If not what is it then instead?

Comment: Hi, I have created a VIEW using the "views_data_export" mode but because my views have like 9000 nodes I can't just display it as normal link to a "Database views" because it would generate for to long and thats the reason why I'm using this method to save it to a local file

Comment: Hi, I never said there isn't a different solution than what I'm trying to do, but it is the only thing I know how to do.. without rebuilding my views from json / xml files and their templates from scratch thats why I'm trying to do it in that way. 

So completely different approach may be good but may require rebuilding everythink from scratch. I want to create JSON/XML from views_data_export module and it almost works minus the small problems which I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Asking for general advice on a number of different questions isn't suitable for Q+A. Please ask a single, specific, narrowly-focused question at a time, and rather than asking for general advice, detail exactly what steps you've taken, exactly which small part of the problem you're trying to solve right now, and where that's going wrong so far. That way we'll have a bunch of smaller, easier to address, more generic questions that will help a broader audience than those trying to the exact thing you're trying to do. Many thanks

Comment: Hi thanks for the welcome but.. 1) it is not "General advice" I asked very specific question related to very specific problem and I think I have described the process correctly 2) I pointed out what I'm trying to achieve in points 1,2,3,4 to be more specific, so you don't think anyone would help? :(

Comment: Q+A works best when it's one question per question - at the moment you have four completely separate questions about one module, which can't be solved using a single approach/method. Combining two modules into one is completely unrelated to creating a cron job, and so on, plus you didn't ask a specific question about that first one...what could a succinct response to that look like without being able to see the full code for each? How would it be useful to future visitors given that the chances of someone else needing to combine the same two exact modules is very slim? That sort of thing

Comment: Hi, so in order for me to create more specific questions I should remove the pointed out problems that I see with my current solution ? ok I have done that and removed the additional question and just asked a question regarding combining two modules into one and I have also provided entire code for both modules well on each of the module there is <? at beggining line but it didn't allowed me to add that. there is also info file but I don't think he is crucial ? I can copy paste it in description as well.

Comment: And in regards how it can be useful for "Future visitors" I suppose knowing a solution of how to combine functionality into 1 module than just creating copies of same module is good in general? But your saying that I can ask questions that only other users may need help with ? so.. if I have questions OR questions (But you allow only for one question) what should I do? wait for others to have problems with it ? or just ask a question / questions, worst case scenario is that none will provide answer

Comment: To sum it up, I really feel guilty now for asking "drupal questions" on "drupal answers" like I did something wrong , but I didn't, I just asked a question with more questions and got flamed for it and you asked me to remove my questions because they were to specific ? they were all connected to my questions thats why I asked them :(

Comment: Hi Gabe, don't feel bad. The mods are quite strict at the moment regarding posted questions because over the past weeks there have been a lot of questions that show no effort whatsoever. Familiarize yourself with the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) and specifically the section about asking questions to prevent these situations in the future. You are more then welcome here and we are really a community of nice people, we are just desperately attempting to guarantee a level of quality. Your edited question looks OK to me and I flagged it for reopening.

Comment: No one "flamed" you, come on now. You were simply asked to break your multiple questions down into individual ones so that they conform to the format here. Yes, worst case scenario is that no one will answer any of them, as is the case for every question ever posted here. But no one would have answered this in its original form, it would've taken a lot of back and forth to find out what you do and don't know, and an explanation of multiple unrelated concepts and disciplines. Our format just doesn't suit that; there's nothing to feel guilty about. Looks good now, thanks for the edit, it's open

Comment: Hi Neograph734, thanks for kind reply, Clive thanks for reopening it now

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should be able to merge them into one module by first checking if the view is available in the batch (stop otherwise) and provide the filename within this check. Code has not been tested though.

```
function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_alter(&$batch, &$batch_redirect) {
  // Check for Denmark.
  if ($view = views_get_view($batch['produkty_denmark_xml'])) {
    $filename = 'denmark.xml';
  }
  // Check for Sweden.
  elseif ($view = views_get_view($batch['produkty_json'])) {
     $filename = 'producty.json';
  }
  // Check for Norway.
  // ... Code goes here

  // Leave if nothing was found.
  else return;

  // Proceed if something was found.

  // Add in another operation that will store the file on the server in a location
  // of our choosing.
  $batch['operations'][] = array(
    'dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish', array($batch['eid'], $filename),
  );
}

function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish($eid, $filename) {
  $export = views_data_export_get($eid);
  $view = views_data_export_view_retrieve($eid);
  $view->set_display($export->view_display_id);
  $view->display_handler->batched_execution_state = $export;
  $view->display_handler->remove_index();

  // Get path to temp file
  $temp_file = $view->display_handler->outputfile_path();
  file_unmanaged_copy($temp_file, 'public://'. $filename, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```

There might however be a bigger problem with your module. I cannot see your hook menu implementation, but if anonymous users are also able to access `domain.com/denmark` they could DDoS your site. Prevent that.

Comment: Hi Neograph734, thank you for your answer :) it really seems like it should work but it doesn't I mean if I go to /sweden or /denmark it does start generating a view but it doesn't save it in public:// I'm not sure why it may be like that the url looks like this after finishing export: sweden?download=1&eid=28&token=E8TFFtDTQnuGOO8tbeshmy6oN_jfbdPTKWkSQiYjqoA

But it doesn't save it to a file I'm not sure why (regarding hook menu it is great idea, but I don't know how to do it as well as you may imagine )

Comment: That token already implies there is DDoS protection in place, so if you request the page without the token I suppose it would not generate (but it is out of scope of this question). Could you try replacing `if ($view = views_get_view($batch['produkty_denmark_xml']))` with `if isset($batch['produkty_denmark_xml'])) {` (for all contries)? Loading the view does not seems to be required.

Comment: I have added it but now I can't activate module I get internal server error 500 whenever I try to enable it, it is possible to enable other module https://paste.ee/p/BMwNd

Comment: That would imply a syntax error in this module... I see I missed a bracket after the `if`: `if (isset($batch['produkty_denmark_xml'])) {`

Comment: now it was possible to enable the module, but it still doesn't work (sorry for slow reply but I try to check it as good as I can and exporting 9000 products takes a while)

Comment: Then I hope someone else has a better answer. I am out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort Neograph734 I really appreciate it when I mentioned it doesn't work I had on mind that "it still doesn't generate a file or files" as my response saying "it still doesn't work" was not  clear enough

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_alter(&$batch, &$batch_redirect) {
  $view = views_get_view($batch['view_name']);

  drupal_set_message($batch['view_name']);

  // Add in another operation that will store the file on the server in a location
  // of our choosing.
  if($batch['view_name']== "produkty_denmark_xml"){

    $batch['operations'][] = array(
    'dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish', array($batch['eid']),
    );
  }else if($batch['view_name']== "produkty_json"){

    $batch['operations'][] = array(
    'dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish2', array($batch['eid']),
    );
  }
}

function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish($eid) {
  $export = views_data_export_get($eid);
  $view = views_data_export_view_retrieve($eid);
  $view->set_display($export->view_display_id);
  $view->display_handler->batched_execution_state = $export;
  $view->display_handler->remove_index();

  // Get path to temp file
  $temp_file = $view->display_handler->outputfile_path();
  file_unmanaged_copy($temp_file, 'public://denmark.xml', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
function dvm_reports_views_data_export_batch_finish2($eid) {
  $export = views_data_export_get($eid);
  $view = views_data_export_view_retrieve($eid);
  $view->set_display($export->view_display_id);
  $view->display_handler->batched_execution_state = $export;
  $view->display_handler->remove_index();

  // Get path to temp file
  $temp_file = $view->display_handler->outputfile_path();
  file_unmanaged_copy($temp_file, 'public://produkty.json', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
}
```